How to find if the angle one high-dimensional vector makes with another is positive or negative?
Suppose, I have two $D$ dimensional vectors, where $D \sim 10^6$. However, I cannot calculate the cross-product of these two high-dimensional vectors. Then, how do we know if the angle that vector $a$ makes with vector $b$ is positive or negative?
While it may be possible to calculate the individual angles along each axis using the projected vectors, if I do $cos^{-1}(\theta)$, where $\theta = \frac{\sum_i^D a_i b_i}{\lVert a \rVert\lVert b \rVert}$, I only get positive values of angle in torch or numpy.
How to obtain negative values as well depending on the position of vector $b$ with respect of vector $a$?

Please define what you mean by a "negative angle". Please give a two dimensional example.

@Somos What I wanted to say here is that, if you take the vector $a$ to be the x-axis in a 2D plane, then the angle that vector $b = [1,1]$ makes is positive (in the anti-clockwise direction), and the angle that the vector $b' = [1,-1]$ makes is negative (in the clockwise direction).

Your problem is not a mathematics problem, but a software problem. Please try the easy two dimensional example you gave as a sanity check.
